# Dataset for Ethereum applications

Tags: blockchain

i am searching for public available datasets from projects, in which the blockchain technology would be "useful". For example projects like supply chainys or trading (e.g. in the energy market). I couldn't find anything, but maybe somone here knows more?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [stateofthedapps.com](https://www.stateofthedapps.com/) which lists and categorises most of the Blockchain projects in the Ethereum space and more.

> The curated list of decentralized applications. Explore decentralized
>   applications (apps built on Blockchain). Discover the possibilities of
>   the Ethereum, EOS & POA blockchain with the definitive registry of
>   ÐApp projects.

Comment: That is a good idea thanks, but is there a way to find out, when a transation has been started? For example when i look at the Storj project, i can see the list of it's transactions here https://etherscan.io/address/0xb64ef51c888972c908cfacf59b47c1afbc0ab8ac?utm_source=StateOfTheDApps , but there i can only find out, when a transaction has been finished.